# Aligning enumerate command with theorem

Tags: lists

I want to align all the alphabets of the list with the word Theorem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{thm}
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a pronormal subgroup of $G$. Then  the following statements hold.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item If $H \leq K \leq G$, then $H$ prn $K$.
\item If $H \leq K \unlhd G$, then $G = N_G(H)K$, hence the Frattini argument applies to pronormal subgroups.
\item If $K \unlhd G$, then $HK$ prn $G$. Furthermore, $HK/K$ prn $G/K$. 
\end{thm}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some more keys from `enumitem`. I also added some fixes: for unknown reasons, `\lhd`, `\unlhd`, `\rhd` and `\unrhd` are declared as binary operation symbols; I added a `\prn` command for “is pronormal in”.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newcommand{\prn}{\mathrel{\mathrm{prn}}}

% fix the wrong setting for some commands
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lhd}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\unlhd}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rhd}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"42}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\unrhd}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"44}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a pronormal subgroup of $G$. Then  the following statements hold.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\alph*)},leftmargin=*,align=left]
\item If $H \leq K \leq G$, then $H \prn K$.
\item If $H \leq K \unlhd G$, then $G = N_G(H)K$, hence the Frattini argument applies to pronormal subgroups.
\item If $K \unlhd G$, then $HK \prn G$. Furthermore, $HK/K \prn G/K$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `\textup` if you prefer italics.